# while, if and for loops. First letter, last letter game on Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get this working. Basically i Have to make a game in which a word is randomly generated from a words.txt file and then alternating players have to type a word which starts with the last letter of the previous word. I think I have the basic jist of it but there are a few issues in which I need to iron out.

First off could someone please tell me why my code isn't working? When I run it and type a word that should make finished == True it doesnt seem to recognise it.
Code is as follows:

```
import random

def dictionary_list():
    dictionary = open("words.txt","r")
    dictionary_list = dictionary.read()
    dictionary_list = dictionary_list.split()
    dictionary.close()
    return dictionary_list

def start_word(dictionary_list):
    random_number = random.randrange(0,len(dictionary_list))
    random_word = dictionary_list[random_number]
    print("Starting word: ", random_word)
    return random_word

def get_word(player_number):
    word = input(player_number)
    return word


def get_player_number(player_number):
    if player_number == 1:
        player_number = 2
    else:
        player_number = 1
    return player_number

def main():
    word_list = dictionary_list()
    starting_word = start_word(word_list)
    words_used_list = [starting_word]
    print(words_used_list)
    finished = False
    previous_word = starting_word
    count = 0
    player_number = 1
    while finished == False:
        word = get_word(player_number)
        last_letter_word = previous_word[-1]
        if word[0] != last_letter_word:
            finished == True
        elif word not in word_list:
            finished == True
        elif word in words_used_list:
            finished == True

        elif finished == True:
            print("=" * 40)
            print("Winner is player",player_number)
            print("Number of words played", count)
            print("List of words:", words_used_list)
            print("Losing word: ", word)
            print("=" * 40)
        else:
            player_number = get_player_number(player_number)
            previous_word = word
            count = count + 1
            words_used_list.append(word)

main()
```

Here is a screenshot of what the required output should be like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQICn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have this

```
 elif word in words_used_list:
            finished == True
```

When you mean this:

```
 elif word in words_used_list:
            finished = True
```

(and similar in 2 other places)

Note also that you can say

```
while finished:
```

instead of

```
while finished == True:
```

which might be considered a little more elegant.

Comment: Yay!  Glad to help.   Be sure to click the friendly "accepted answer" tick mark before you leave ;)

Comment: @Waterdogs In python, it's standard to make comparisons to False/True/None using the 'is' operator. That might have prevented this, because seeing 'x == True' would throw up warning signs.